# Changing Contenteditable type to number Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

i want my cordova app to show a soft keyboard of numbers only.
in an `input`, i can easily change the `type to number` but in the `contenteditable table`, im not finding a way to do it.
Is there a way to change the type not validate the input?

Comment: Please consider including some code

Comment: please add some code here its not proper here.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard` this extension.

it will open number keyboard properly on `contenteditable` `table`